# TypeError: Input 'e' of 'SelectV2' Op has type int64 that does not match type int32 of argument 't'

Tags: python, training-data

I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/examples/summarization-tf.ipynb) with another model called *AraBART* and another Arabic dataset called *xlsum*. I get an error while execution this instraction:

```
model.fit(
    train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=1
)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py:1279 run_call_with_unpacked_inputs  *
        return func(self, **unpacked_inputs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/mbart/modeling_tf_mbart.py:1300 call  *
        labels = tf.where(
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:4716 where_v2
        return gen_math_ops.select_v2(condition=condition, t=x, e=y, name=name)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:8912 select_v2
        "SelectV2", condition=condition, t=t, e=e, name=name)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:558 _apply_op_helper
        inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))

    TypeError: Input 'e' of 'SelectV2' Op has type int64 that does not match type int32 of argument 't'.
```

I can't understand what is this error

Answer (score 1):

As the errors says, it seems that the variable 't' is supposed to have a dtype of 'int32', but your data samples are of type 'int64', so just need to convert your data samples to dtype 'int32' by using `tf.cast(..., int32)` or by setting variable 't' dtype to int64.

Comment: You have suggested two possible steps to consider, Pls make them visible distinctively. Also provide more information on how to apply the changes you suggested.